# regex for matching string contains brackets with string between them only

Tags: regex

I is there a regex that can match only the text inside brackets for example

- `(text) (text) (text)` it should match
- `(text) normal text (text)` shouldn't match
- `Normal text` shouldn't match
- `Normal text (text)` shouldn't match

I have tried this regex

```
/^(?![A-Za-z])(?:(\(.*?\)){1,})([A-Za-z])$/
```

it matches all the cases except when we have
(text) normal text (text) it matches when it shouldn't

Comment: Like `^\([^()]*\)(?:\s+\([^()]*\))*$`?

Comment: So an empty string is valid, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
^\s*(?:\([^()]*\)\s*)+$
```

It matches any number of repetitions of `(...)` groups, with whitespace before and between them.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/XUDZdz/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you start the pattern with `(` you don't need the negative lookahead `(?![A-Za-z])`, and you can omit `([A-Za-z])$` as that would match a single char at the end of the string.

You might use a pattern like matching chars a-z and whitespace chars:

```
^\([A-Za-z\s]+\)(?:\s*\([A-Za-z\s]+\))*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1Q5dRa/1)

Or more general using a negated character class:

`^\([^()]*\)(?:\s*\([^()]*\))*$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5N5qK4/1)

Comment: it won't work when tested on this example

"(upbeat music) (upbeat music continues) (upbeat music continues) (upbeat music continues) (upbeat music continues) (upbeat music continues)"

Comment: @AwniRifai Then you can use the second pattern, see https://regex101.com/r/UHNtMs/1